# Is ThreadPool worth it in this scenario?

Tags: c#, multithreading, compact-framework, threadpool, barcode-scanner

I have a thread that I fire off every time the user scans a barcode.

Most of the time it is a fairly short running thread.  But sometimes it can take a very long time (waiting on a invoke to the GUI thread).

I have read that it may be a good idea to use the ThreadPool for this rather than just creating my own thread for each scan.

But I have also read that if the ThreadPool runs out of threads then it will just wait until some other thread exits (not OK for what I am doing).

So, how likely is it that I am going to run out of threads?  And is the benefit of the ThreadPool really worth it?  (When I scan it does not seem to take too long for the scan to "run" the thread logic.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "a very long time" and how common that scenario is.

The MSDN topic "[The Managed Thread Pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx)" offers good guidelines for when **not** to use thread pool threads:

> There are several scenarios in which it is appropriate to create and manage your own threads instead of using thread pool threads:
>
> - You require a foreground thread.
> - You require a thread to have a particular priority.
> - You have tasks that cause the thread to block for long periods of time. The
>   thread pool has a maximum number of
>   threads, so a large number of blocked
>   thread pool threads might prevent
>   tasks from starting.
> - You need to place threads into a single-threaded apartment. All
>   ThreadPool threads are in the
>   multithreaded apartment.
> - You need to have a stable identity associated with the thread, or to
>   dedicate a thread to a task.

Comment: Hmmm, my scenario will fit some of those some times.  Sounds like I best not go with the threadpool.

Answer (score 1):

Since the user will never scan more than one barcode at a time, the memory costs of the threadpool might not be worth it - I'd stick with a single thread just waiting in the background.

Comment: If there is analysis going on (as the user indicates) then it is feasible that the GUI allows >1 scans to happen.

Comment: I suspect this isn't the case, because it would be weird from a UI perpective (one scan completes, then user is looking at results, then suddenly another one pops in?)

Comment: @Hassan, @Paul - Actually I do have more than one scan at a time, kindof.  When the user scans, sometimes the result of that scan is to open a new window and allow a scan in that window.  (Infact, that is why this is on a thread (if it were not then the first scan would block the scan event for the second scan).

Comment: You already have a ThreadPool set up with a few default threads. Using it might _reduce_ memory costs.

Answer (score 1):

The point of the thread pool is to amortize the cost of creating threads, which are not inexpensive to spin up and tear down. If you have a short-running task, the cost of creating/destroying the thread can be a significant portion of the overall run-time. The maximum number of threads in the thread pool depends on the version of the .NET Framework, typically dozens to hundreds per processor. The number of threads is scaled depending on available work.

Will you run out of threads and have to wait for a thread to become available? It depends on your workload. You can get the maximum number of threads available via ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(). Chances are (based on the description of your problem) that this number is sufficiently high.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.getmaxthreads.aspx

Another option would be to manage your own pool of scan threads and assign them work rather than creating a new thread for every scan. Personally I would try the threadpool first and only manage your own threads if it proved necessary. Even better, I would look into async programming techniques in .NET. The methods will be run on the thread pool, but give you a much nicer programming experience than manual thread management.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Alas, the main async programing technique in .NET (BeginInvoke) is not available on the Compact Framework.

Comment: Life is definitely different on the CF. I've only dabbled there and that was years ago. Unfortunate that useful constructs like BeginInvoke still aren't available.

Answer (score 0):

If most of the time it is short running threads you could use the thread pool or a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) which draws threads from the pool.

Answer (score 0):

An advantage I can see in your case is that threadpool class puts an upper limit on the amount of threads that may be active. It depends on the context of your application whether you will exhaust system resources. Exhausting a modern desktop system is VERY hard to do really.

If the software is used in a supermarket till it is highly unlikely that you will have more then 5 barcodes being analysed at the same time. If its run in a back-end server for a whole row of supermarket tills. Then perhaps 30-100 concurrent requests might be active.

With this sort of theory crafting it is highly unlikely that you will run out of threads, even on embedded hardware. If you have a dozen or so requests active at a time, and your code works, it's ok to just leave it as it is.

A thread pool is just an abstraction though, and you could have queue in the middle that queues request onto a thread-pool, in this scenario for the row-of-till example above, I'd feel comfortable queueing 100-1000 requests against a threadpool with 10 threads.

Answer (score 0):

In .net (and on windows in general), the question should always be reversed: "Is creating a new thread worth it in this scenario?"

Creating a new thread is expensive, and doing it over and over again is almost certainly not worth it. The thread pool is cheap, and really should be the first thing you turn to when you need a new thread.

If you decide to spin up a new thread, soon you will start worrying about re-using the thread if it's already running. Then you will start worrying that sometimes the thread is running but it seems to be taking too long, and so you should make a new one. Then you're going to decide to have a thread not exit immediately upon finishing work, but to wait a little while in case new work comes in. And then... bam! You've created your own thread pool. At which point you should just back up and use the system-provided one.

The folks who mentioned that the thread pool might "run out of threads" were well-intentioned, but they did you a disservice. The limit on the number of threads in the thread pool is quite large. If you run into it, you have other problems.

(And, of course, since .net 2.0, you can set the maximum number of threads, so you can tweak the number if you absolutely have to.)

Others have directed you to MSDN: "[The Managed Thread Pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx)". I will repeat that direction, as the article is good, but in my mind does not sell the thread pool hard enough. :)